# Book with a unicorn stampede on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I found this book on a shopping website. I know which shop but the problem is that the shop isn't returning the book when I search via the site's search bar when I try to find it again.

The front cover of the novel shows a unicorn stampede, with a blonde girl between the stampede and the viewer, her back facing us. I think she's standing on a cliff.

Comment: @JohnRennie OP clarified in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275288/4918 that they meant a unicorn stampede. That should be enough details so I'll voted to reopen the question. Nevertheless, OP, if you can recall any more details, please edit them into the question. In particular, please tell us what webshop it is, that can help us narrow down the answer.

Comment: OK :-) I do hope [it's not this book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23262546-violated-by-monsters). I worry about some authors.

Comment: Yeah not close sorry

Comment: What shopping website was it?

Comment: @JohnRennie, really, gangbangs with unicorns!?!?!?! And i thought unicorns were the purest of animals.

Comment: [The Unicorn Song](https://tomsmith.bandcamp.com/track/my-unicorn-song)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps this is [*A Plague of Unicorns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QETA0ME) (2014) by Jane Yolen.

> In this historical fiction-meets-fantasy novel by award-winning author Jane Yolen, readers 8-12 will experience a world where a young boy with nothing but questions may have the only answer to solving a unicorn infestation at a medieval abbey.
>
> When young James asks one too many questions, his mother and uncle hope an education at Cranford Abbey will make him a proper noble—but when James arrives, the monks there are most interested in keeping the unicorns in the orchard from eating all the prized golden apples they need to save the abbey. Abbot Aelian thinks he knows how to defeat the ravenous unicorns, though it may actually be up to James to use his inquisitive mind to find a way to save Cranford Abbey and hopefully find a way to return home.
>
> [image]

The cover shows a blonde boy viewed from the back, a stampeding herd of white unicorns and the golden apples.

Comment: @Valorum because I think the Google Books link is more stable (less likely to link rot), has a better presentation, and links you to multiple different sites selling the book instead of trying to sell it themselves exclusively. Also the Amazon page got angry at me is giving me a captcha trying to ensure that I'm not a robot before it shows me the information.

Comment: @Valorum But even if you give just the Amazon link, I would prefer if the post clearly states that that's where the description in this post comes from (as long as you keep this description).

Comment: Personally I go with Goodreads if there's a choice. Their links seem very stable indeed, and the descriptions are usually very detailed, often with the official blurb *and* and a range of reviews